# Disabling buttons in the next form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have form1 and form2 in my project. form1 is login page, after logging I get into form2. I have also created a database table for form1 with username and password, with admin and user as 2 entities and related records too. where form2 contains 2 buttons admin and users.
the question is.. when i log in as an admin i want all the buttons in form2 enabled..when logged in as user i only want users button to be enabled and admin to be disabled.
please could anyone help me with this coding ..?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a reference to the user role in the show command like this

```
form2.Show(IsAdmin);
```

and then accept it in form2's constructor:

```
public Form2(bool IsAdmin)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    if (IsAdmin) ... else ...
}
```

You may also want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728201/two-picturebox-in-two-different-forms/22729125#22729125) lengthier discussion on the topic of referencing one form from another.

Answer (score 1):

As [TaW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3152130/taw) said, the flag parameter in form2's constructor should run.

Another possibility is to create a property in form2:

```
    private bool isAdmin;

    public bool IsAdmin
    {
        get
        {
            return isAdmin;
        }

        set
        {
            isAdmin = value;
            btnAdmin.Enabled = isAdmin;
        }
    }
```

and use it in form 1 before you show form2.
For an admin:

```
    var f = new Form2 { IsAdmin = true };
    f.Show();
```

For a normal user:

```
    var f = new Form2 { IsAdmin = false };
    f.Show();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you login as admin from form1 then open form2 and close form1.
Take a flag vaiable.

```
flag=0;
If (username==admin && password=="Your Password")
form2.show()
this.close()
flag=1;
End If
```

Now in form2 check the value of flag. If it is 1 then logged in as admin else logged in as user.
So,

```
If form1.flag=1 then
admin_button.enabled=true
user_button.enabled=true
else
admin_button.enabled=false
user_button.enabled=true
End If
```

Comment: Hi - is this a solution, or just an attempt to figure out where the error is? if it's a solution - can you give a bit more explanation about how this solves the problem?