# C# WinForm: Displaying Object variables in ListBox

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have a class which contains my object format;
Priority, Title and Description.

My BindingList is in the Form2 class.
In Form1 I have a Listbox. When I create an object via the windows form, the object appears in the ListBox. (in the format of [namespace.object].

I attempted to use

```
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Title;
    }
```

in my object class to display the object title, however, all this does is results in an empty field being added to the ListBox.

How would I add the Priority and Title sections of the object to the ListBox?

Thanks in advance!
Will.

Comment: So Title probaly is empty. Show us the class and how you add it to the ListBox!

Comment: http://www.codeshare.io/aXf4o

Comment: Loos ok so far but what is in  ` memoTitle.Text` when you initialize the List? Set the Debugger into the ToString method to see what is there! Sometimes it helps to add a little to the returned string like: `return "Title=" + Title;`

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to do that! I've only just started using VS.

Comment: You click to the gray area  all to the left of the line ` return Title;` so that a fat red dot appears. Now you run the program and when it stops you can hover over Title and see its value. __Do learn about the Debugger!__  It is by far your best friend, much better than StackOverflow!!

Comment: Excellent, thanks! It's returning a value of "", so I'm guessing it's not adding the objects to the list :S

Comment: You can examine all variables in your programm (if they are in scope). Maybe memosList.Count is > 0 but the members are emtpy.. You can set breakpoints anywhere and also set watches. Very powerful and essential!

Comment: The properties in the CreateMemo method are also coming up as null when debugging - I'm not sure what's wrong there as its the next step from entering the values in the form and clicking 'save'.

Comment: I think I may have it - the "this.Close(); was stopping the values from being passed to the CreateMemo method - is there any way to delay the closing of form2 so the values can be passed first? :)

Comment: `string priority` is only a local variable, so it is not saved anywhere. How to save stuff from one form into things in another form is a classic question, asked ca. a million times  here. One option is to put it as a global public variable in the program.cs file another to set/exchange references upon opening the 2nd form..   BTW, you class has members but no actual Property (since the members don't have getters/setters..) but that is not the point.

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22740787/disabling-buttons-in-the-next-form/22740855?s=3|0.3887#22740855) shows how to pass a reference (to a bool) when opening a form. This is probably the best way to solve your problem..

Comment: Of course you could also Hide the from2 instead of Closing it; not sure if that works well as I don't know when andhow you show/open it..

Comment: Hiding it should be fine :) Thanks for the help! Especially in regards to VS Debugger - should help a lot! Unfortunately I don't have enough rep yet to upvote your answers, but I'll remember to come back and do it when I do! :)

Comment: Good luck and have fun!