# Is it possible to link three Forms together?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

So far, I can only link 2 Forms together.
The reason I need to link 3 Forms together is because I have `InventoryForm` and `MainForm`, which can both open or show my `SupplierForm` (`supplierform.show();`).

I need to refresh the data on my `InventoryForm.dataGridView1` after doing some process in my `SupplierForm`.
The problem is when I set a parameter on `SupplierForm` to hold/get the `InventoryForm`, like this:

```
public SupplierForm(InventoryForm inventory)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    inventoryform = inventory;
}
```

and use a method on `InventoryForm` like this:

```
//this is on `SupplierForm`
private void backbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //closes module and .Focus() back to inventory form
    connection.Close();
    inventoryform.RefreshGrid();
    inventoryform.dataGridView1.Sort(inventoryform.dataGridView1.Columns["ItemID"], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    this.Close();
}
```

The `MainForm` is asking for a parameter for `SupplierForm` whenever I try to open or show (`supplierform.show();`) `SupplierForm` using `button1` in my `MainForm`.

I even tried to connect `MainForm` and `SupplierForm` but the problem gets bigger, all Forms that are linked to `MainForm` are now asking for mainform parameter.

Do you happen to know a fix for this?

Comment: Define 'link' ! do you mean the forms' positions? Or data? Binding? References? - Also: Please do fix the formatting!

Comment: @TaW im sorry i dont know what to call it to be more specific. i did my best trust me. newbie here. I think its just a reference maybe? bcoz i just need the methd on InventoryForm  to use  it on SupplierForm which is accessible to both iventoryform and mainform. "Why not just make a method on SupplierForm just like the method on InventoryForm?" I need to refresh the datagridview1 on InventoryForm after doing some process on SupplierForm. wht i mean on refresh is to fill the datagridview1 with newly added data on dtabase thru supplierform. I show supplierform thru InventoryForm as .showdialog()

Comment: OK, that indeed sounds as if you simply want to have references to each form on each form. Have class variables for the references and maybe pass out the main form in the open call (ie the constructor) to the child forms! Add a few public methods and you should be good.

Comment: unfortunately, i donw know how.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22728201/two-picturebox-in-two-different-forms/22729125?s=1|33.5023#22729125) for a few ways to do that..

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions to this, but the simpest is to create an interface:

```
public interface IRefreshable()
{
    void RefreshGrid();
}
```

and implement it in your forms like this:

```
public SupplierForm : IRefreshable
{
    public void RefreshGrid()
    {
         // Your form-specific refresh code goes here
         this.SupplierGrid.Refresh();
    }
}
```

and

```
public MainForm : IRefreshable
{
    public void RefreshGrid()
    {
         // Your other form-specific refresh code goes here
         this.MainGrid.Refresh();
    }
}
```

Implementing an interface is a promise that an object will have that method, without knowing anything else about the object. Now the supplier form can be supplied with either a MainForm or InventoryForm parameter. It doesn't care which, because they both have their own version of RefreshGrid.

```
public SupplierForm
{
    private IRefreshable parentform;

    public SupplierForm(IRefreshable parent)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        parentform = parent;
    }

//this is on `SupplierForm`
private void backbutton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //closes module and .Focus() back to inventory form
    connection.Close();
    parentform.RefreshGrid();
    this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Interfaces promise clean solutions. But they still need to be __implemented__. The question, I believe, is about __how__ to implement..

Answer (score 0):

If you know there will only one instance of each form you could use a static helperclass
for example:

```
public static class formHelper
{
    static InventoryForm InvForm;
    static SuplierForm SupForm;
    static MainForm MnForm;
}
```

You can acces the variables from everywhere within the namespace using `formHelper.InventoryForm`. But before that you need to set the variables to contain the right form:

```
public MainForm() //the constructor
{
    formHelper.MnForm = this;
}
```

Do this in the constructor of each form change the names of course.

Methods that you call from on the different forms still need to be created on each but hoding the refrences is much easier and accesable. I hope this helps you somehow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple constructors like this :

```
    public SupplierForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
   public SupplierForm(InventoryForm inventory) :this()
   {
     InitializeComponent();

     inventoryform = inventory;
   }
```